# How to restrict the merge request to be executed only from and to specific branches?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-flow

I am trying to implement git flow with GitLab.
The flow of merge requests should be restricted. For example, it should not be allowed to create a merge request from a feature branch to main.

Can I solve this with git server side hooks?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can [require everyone to submit merge requests for a protected branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#require-everyone-to-submit-merge-requests-for-a-protected-branch), you can try and:

- protect the target branch
- from the `Allowed to merge list`, select a group which does *not* include Developers.
- from the `Allowed to push` list, select `No one`.

That way, merge request to that branch should not be possible from developers.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I don't want to restrict the users. I want to restrict that merge requests can only be created from the feature to the development branch.  For example, it should not be allowed to create a merge request from the development branch to the main branch.

Comment: @Znar Yes, that is why is use a group different from Developer, since I am not aware of permission per branch.

Comment: Hmm, but every developer should be allowed to create a merge request.

Comment: @Znar " it should not be allowed to create a merge request from a feature branch to main.": so developers should *not* be allowed to create a merge request to main, right?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just wanted to give an example.
Let's take the flow from feature to development branch as an example.
All developers should be able to create that MR.
It should not be possible to create a MR from feature to main or release branch.

Comment: @Znar Would my proposition to protect main or release branch the way I describe in the answer achieve just that? All developers would still be able to create a MR from feature to dev.

Comment: nope. I try to a adapt git flow.
I need to restrict multiple merge requests branches.